# While loop not working even when condition is satisfied

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have an assignment to write a C++ program for basic atm functioning. There is a rule to be followed that in one day, a max of 50,000 cash can flow through the atm, that includes all cash transfers, withdrawals or fast cash. I put a while loop over the whole body which uses a "atmlimit" integer to test the condition. Every successful cash transaction gets added into it but the loop is not working for some reason.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pincode, pindigit1;
    int availbalance, userchoice;
    int transmoney, inputFC, ubinput;
    int cwmoney, ctmoney, spam;
    int atmlimit;

    cout << "\n           Please enter your 4-digit pin code \n           Enter 'break' at any point to close the process \n" << endl;
    cin >> pincode;

    pindigit1 = pincode;

    for (pindigit1; pindigit1 >= 10; pindigit1 /= 10);

    availbalance = 10000 * pindigit1;

    while (atmlimit <= 50000) {

    menu:
        cout << "\n        *******************************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   Please choose the service your require by entering its respective number  *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [1] Fast Cash                                                             *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [2] Cash Withdrawl                                                        *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [3] Balance Inquiry                                                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [4] Cash Transfer                                                         *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *******************************************************************************  \n" << endl;
        cin >> userchoice;

        if (userchoice == 1) {

        ta:

            cout << "\n          Choose the amount of money you want to send by entering its respective number or enter 0 to go back to menu" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [1] 500Rs                     [2] 1000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [3] 2000Rs                    [4] 3000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [5] 4000Rs                    [6] 5000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [7] 10000Rs                   [8] 20000Rs \n" << endl;
            cin >> inputFC;

            if (inputFC == 8) {
                transmoney = 20000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 7) {
                transmoney = 10000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 6) {
                transmoney = 5000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 5) {
                transmoney = 4000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 4) {
                transmoney = 3000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 3) {
                transmoney = 2000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 2) {
                transmoney = 1000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 1) {
                transmoney = 500;
            }

            if (inputFC == 0) {
                goto menu;
            }

            if (transmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      Your transaction completed successfully" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += transmoney;
                availbalance -= transmoney;

                goto menu;
            }

            if (transmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      You have insufficient balance to perform this transaction. Enter '0' to go back the menu or '1' to change the transaction amout" << endl;
                cin >> ubinput;
            }

            if (ubinput == 0) {
                goto menu;
            }
            if (ubinput == 1) {
                goto ta;
            }
        }

        if (userchoice == 2) {
        cwmenu:
            cout << "\n                      Please enter the amount of cash you want to withdraw from your bank account \n              Enter 0 if you want to return to the menu \n" << endl;
            cin >> cwmoney;

            cout << cwmoney; //TBR

            if (cwmoney == 0) {
                goto menu;
            }

            if (cwmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                       Your transaction bas been processed, Thank you!\n" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += cwmoney;
                availbalance -= cwmoney;

                goto menu;
            }
            else if (cwmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      You have insufficient balance for this transaction. \n" << endl;
                goto cwmenu;
            }
        }

        if (userchoice == 3) {
            cout << "\n                    Your current bank balance is " << availbalance << "Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
            goto menu;
        }

        if (userchoice == 4) {
        ctmenu:

            cout << "\n                      Enter the  receiver's 6 digit bank account number \n                       Enter 0 to return to the menu" << endl;
            cin >> spam;
            if (spam == 0) {
                goto menu;
            }

            cout << "\n                   Please enter the amount of cash you want to transfer/send \n                             Enter 0 if you want to return to the menu \n" << endl;
            cin >> ctmoney;

            if (ctmoney == 0) {
                goto menu;
            }

            cout << "\n" << endl;

            cout << ctmoney << endl; //TBD

            if (ctmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      Your transaction bas been processed, Thank you!\n" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += availbalance;
                availbalance -= ctmoney;

                goto menu;
            }
            else if (ctmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                       You have insufficient balance for this transaction. \n" << endl;
                goto ctmenu;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n                    You have reached the maximum amount of cash flow through your account, Please try later \n" << endl;
}
```

After all the suggestions, I re-wrote the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pincode, pindigit1;
    int availbalance, userchoice;
    int transmoney, inputFC;
    int cwmoney, ctmoney;
    int atmlimit = 0;

    cout << "\n           Please enter your 4-digit pin code \n           Enter 'break' at any point to close the process \n" << endl;
    cin >> pincode;

    pindigit1 = pincode;

    for (pindigit1 = pincode; pindigit1 >= 10; pindigit1 /= 10)
        ;
    cout << pindigit1 << endl; //TBR

    availbalance = 10000 * pindigit1;
    cout << availbalance << endl; //TBR

    while (atmlimit <= 50000) {

        cout << "\n        *******************************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   Please choose the service you require by entering its respective number  *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [1] Fast Cash                                                             *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [2] Cash Withdrawl                                                        *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [3] Balance Inquiry                                                       *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *   [4] Cash Transfer                                                         *" << endl;
        cout << "\n        *******************************************************************************  \n" << endl;
        cin >> userchoice;

        switch (userchoice) {

        case 1:

            cout << "\n          Choose the amount of money you want to send by entering its respective number or enter 0 to go back to menu" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [1] 500Rs                     [2] 1000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [3] 2000Rs                    [4] 3000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [5] 4000Rs                    [6] 5000Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n          [7] 10000Rs                   [8] 20000Rs \n" << endl;
            cin >> inputFC;

            if (inputFC == 8) {
                transmoney = 20000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 7) {
                transmoney = 10000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 6) {
                transmoney = 5000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 5) {
                transmoney = 4000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 4) {
                transmoney = 3000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 3) {
                transmoney = 2000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 2) {
                transmoney = 1000;
            }

            if (inputFC == 1) {
                transmoney = 500;
            }

            if (inputFC == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            if (transmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      Your transaction completed successfully" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += transmoney;
                availbalance -= transmoney;

                cout << atmlimit << endl; //TBD
                cout << availbalance; //TBD

                continue;
            }

            if (transmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      You have insufficient balance to perform this transaction" << endl;
                continue;
            }

            break;

        case 2:

            cout << "\n                      Please enter the amount of cash you want to withdraw from your bank account \n              Enter 0 if you want to return to the menu \n" << endl;
            cin >> cwmoney;

            cout << cwmoney; //TBR

            if (cwmoney == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            if (cwmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                       Your transaction bas been processed, Thank you!\n" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += cwmoney;
                availbalance -= cwmoney;

                cout << atmlimit << endl;
                cout << availbalance;

                continue;
            }
            else if (cwmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      You have insufficient balance for this transaction. \n" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "\n                    Your current bank balance is idk" << availbalance << "Rs" << endl;
            cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
            break;

        case 4:

            cout << "\n                   Please enter the amount of cash you want to transfer/send \n                             Enter 0 if you want to return to the menu \n" << endl;
            cin >> ctmoney;

            if (ctmoney == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            cout << "\n" << endl;

            cout << ctmoney << endl; //TBD

            if (ctmoney <= availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                      Your transaction bas been processed, Thank you!\n" << endl;
                cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n" << endl;
                atmlimit += ctmoney;
                availbalance -= ctmoney;

                cout << atmlimit << endl; //TBD
                cout << availbalance;

                continue;
            }
            else if (ctmoney > availbalance) {
                cout << "\n                       You have insufficient balance for this transaction. \n" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n                    You have reached the maximum amount of cash flow through your account, Please try later \n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize `int atmlimit = 0;`

Comment: When you `goto menu;` you don't evaluate the condition again. Better to avoid use of `goto`here.

Comment: Turning on [errors and warnings produces a clear culprit](https://godbolt.org/z/x3YvGY)

Comment: @DatNoobProgrammer see the link I just updated, there are three instances of undefined behavior the compiler is warning about

Comment: `for (pindigit1; pindigit1 >= 10; pindigit1 /= 10);` could be `for (pindigit1=pincode; pindigit1 >= 10; pindigit1 /= 10);` and fix one warning  but not fix a bug.

Comment: ***Every successful cash transaction gets added into it but the loop is not working for some reason*** I believe all the instances of `goto menu;` could be replaced with `continue;` and that would evaluate the condition again. None of these cause the condition to be evaluated.

Comment: OMG -- don't use gotos.

Comment: Is this a reverse compiled code? Why so many `if`s & `goto`s? Replace them with proper constructs (`switch`, `break`, `continue`) in the 1st place.

Comment: If I see a problem description of a while loop not working I understand a code structure problem. Any code structure problem of code with gotos is out of scope of my experience and I consider gotos a major obstacle for debugging structure problems. So. Is refactoring or rewriting this without gotos an option?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank u all for the answers, I followed all of your instructions and re-structured my code, and the loop seems to be working but theres another issue now. The loop does break when the condition isn't true, but a transaction may occur even if it causes the 'atmlimit' to increase above 50k. It will carry out the transaction, and then the program will break, im entering the newer code in my question

Comment: @Yunnosch I did rewrote it and removed the goto statements, seems like goto statements are a big No in c++

Comment: Good. Now please review the indentation, currently it is misleading and distracting.

Comment: I fixed that. I cut the text of the new code and reformatted with [http://format.krzaq.cc/](http://format.krzaq.cc/) then typed ``` press enter paste code and type ``` again and press enter.

Comment: "the loop is not working for some reason" What are the symptoms?

Comment: @Yunnosch The loop is working now, the suggestions above fixed the issue but now I'm facing one final issue, read my comment above in which I mentioned drescherjm

Comment: If cleaning up the code has fixed the problem I consider the question on the while loop to be non-reproducable. For clarity and convenience I recommend to create a new question with a [mre] for the new problem. Delete this question in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by replacing goto statements with break/continue and some other small tweaks as mentioned in the comments.